# React: ".map is not a function", should I be using object.keys?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, dictionary, object

I'm doing a simple fetch, storing that in the state then trying to output that json to the page. I don't understand what is wrong with this code and why I am getting "hello.map is not a function":

Google tells me that it could be because I have brackets inside my data or rather an object? But I don't think that is the case otherwise the data spat out to the console wouldn't say it was an Array?:

[image]

The code works fine with data like this:

```
const clients = [
    {
        client: "Client 1",
        codename: "client1"
    },
    {
        client: "Client 2",
        codename: "client2"
    }
];
```

Does the data above not count as having brackets?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Todos = () => {

  const [hello, setHello] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSomething();
    }, []);

    const fetchSomething = () => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json);
                setHello(json);
            })
    }

    return (
    <div>
        
        {hello.map((client, clientIndex) => {
            return (
                <div className="tile" key={clientIndex}>
                    <span>{client.body}</span>
                </div>
            )
        })}

        
    </div>
    )
}
export default Todos;
```

So should I be using something like Object.keys?:

```
{Object.keys(hello).map(key => {
            <span>{key.body}</span>
        })}
```

No error on the above one but I can't seem to get to the data I assume I'm not nesting low enough or something.

I've used .map more than Object.keys so I would prefer to use that but I imagine I would need to manipulate the data somehow to use .map, so would the recommended approach for data like this be to use Object.keys or is there a popular other method?

Anyway, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try this --> ` {(hello || []).map((client, clientIndex) => `

Comment: You initialize `hello` with a bool `const [hello, setHello] = useState(false);` and therefore you can't call map on it. Initialize it with an empty array like so `const [hello, setHello] = useState([]);`

Comment: @Martin thank you so much, such a simple solution, definitely wouldn't have caught that being the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the initial state of `hello` is `false`.

Your component renders before the effect that fetches the data has a chance to run, so it's trying to do `.map` on `false`.

I'd recommend:

- changing the initial value to e.g. `null`: `useState(null);`
- checking whether it is `null` before attempting to map things:

```
if(hello === null) return <>Still loading...</>;
return hello.map(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation and a great solution, really nice. Definitely wouldn't have captured that issue myself, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your value of hello initial state to array.

```
const [hello, setHello] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, a very nice simple solution to my question.